# Are the phrasal verbs have same meaning as the verb are redundant?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

[Source](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fall-down)

> I **fell down** and hurt my knee.
>
> I **fell** and hurt my knee.

[Source](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/add-up)

> Now **add up** the number of calories you have eaten.
>
> Now **add** the number of calories you have eaten.

How would I know if the phrasal verb should be used or not when in fact the sentence with the verb means the same? Is it just a matter of choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I **fell down** and hurt my knee.
>   I **fell** and hurt my knee.

mean the same thing because *fall* along with *hurt* imply a downward motion.

> Now add up the number of calories you have eaten.

Here **add up** means "total of the calories of individual food items". But in:

> Now **add** the number of calories you have eaten.

*add* requires 2 quantities to add together, while this example only has one. You would need to say:

> Now **add** the number of calories you have eaten to your age in months.

meaning (the number of calories you have eaten) + (your age in months).

Comment: The last sentence is not understood by me, especially the phrase **eaten to your age**.

Comment: It would be like (the number of calories you have eaten) + (your age in months). Sorry it was not meant to be a logical example. I just wanted to follow the wording in your example.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the phrasal verbs have same meaning as the verb are redundant?

Yes, but sometimes in English redundancy is desired, for these reasons:

- emphasis
- making language colorful or interesting
- clarity (extra syllables in a sentence give the listener time to catch up)
- presence (extra syllables in a sentence sometimes make the sentence seem more important)
- rhythm

That being said, there is a slight possible difference in meaning between *fall* and *fall down* but it could probably be explained as a matter of emphasis.

> I fell down and hurt my knee = Your butt touched the ground or you had to get up after you fell.
>
> I fell and hurt my knee = You may not have actually landed on the ground.